# Absolute value query on table on display a single result

Tags: sql

I have an issue where I am trying to fetch the difference between the each product price and the average product price.

I made some code to fetch the absolute value difference of product price greater than the average product price.

```
select * , ABS(P_PRICE - avg(P_PRICE)) as Difference from product;
```

When I run the code above I get one single product and the difference from the average price when I am trying to get a list of all products and their average prices
This is what the product table looks like:[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8yAt.png)

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you are using an aggregation function with no `GROUP BY` clause, which means that you end up getting aggregated results for all data, i.e. one row. You need to compute the average price separately and then subtract it from each product's price. Something like this:

```
SELECT p1.*, ABS(p1.P_PRICE - p2.avg_price) AS Difference
FROM product p1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(P_PRICE) AS avg_price FROM product) p2
```

Or you can generate the average price in a subquery, but this will probably be less efficient.

```
SELECT *, ABS(P_PRICE - (SELECT AVG(P_PRICE) AS avg_price FROM product)) AS Difference
FROM product
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65bf317cd34bfbadbf3d5a53a61a0d79)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was playing with it a bit and found that this query works for me:
Can't really explain why it works tho.

Hope someone can explain it

```
select *, ABS(P_PRICE - (select avg(P_PRICE) from product)) as Difference from product
```